# Css not working in chrome, (works in edge or if i open the file locally on my pc)

Tags: html, css

I am building a site in html and css for school. i can't use bootstrap and need to use media queries. http://544518.student4a9.ao-ica.nl/index.html is the link of the site. the site is working in google microsoft edge or if i open the html files locally on my PC. It is not working if i open the site in chrome because there needs to be a border around the bas broekhoven text and the "profiel" button is dislocated. The layout, logo and design is a joke :). thanks for your help.

I tried using some webkits in the media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #logo {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #pf{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
    #profielknop{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .item2{
        display: none;
    }
    #linkding{
        display: none;
    }
    #text{
        float: left;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        .kippetje{
            display: none;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That logo "portfolio" reminds me something, but I can't tell what. I'm sure that it starts with "por" too

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/7aa864VtWS
Check this out! I have opened from chrome it is working fine

Comment: Try using CTRL+F5 to load the page without cache; it's working for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reload with Ctrl + F5 ? The page is exactly the same for me between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: wut now it's working. i have tried that 5 times before. probably it ttok time to upload the files to the server or something... Thanks.